# AJAX hogging all the echo from php, no push notifications are getting echoed

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, frontend

here is a small snipper of code that has been drivin gme crazy for 2 nights:
push-notifications.php:

```
<?php
// set content type to server sent events
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
// This function sends updates to the server.
function send_notice($title, $message)
{
  $data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'message' => $message
  );
  $json = json_encode($data);

  echo "event: pushNotification\n";
  echo "data: $json\n\n";
}

// This receives AJAX post request from the client side.
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $thi = $_POST['object'];
  $act = $_POST['status'];
  $update = true;
}
// Im trying to send the stuff i receve from AJAX to the push notification but eve
  send_notice($thi, $act);
```

No matter what i do, ajax hoggs up the output even from send_notice which is outisde the if condition.. What am i missing ?

How can i tell AJAX this is end. Let the next echo statement go to server notifications instead ??

Please any help is apprectated !

Trued to add flsuh:
ob_flush() and flush()
nothing worked,

Tried to put tje send_notice in a while loop and set a condition from inside the if "POST" method. but it still didnt work

The code on the client side that receives this request is :

```
// create a new EventSource object to listen for server push notifications
var source = new EventSource('push-notifications.php');

// handle incoming push notifications
source.addEventListener('pushNotification', function(event) {
  var notification = JSON.parse(event.data);

  // show the notification to the user
  console.log(notification.title + '\n' + notification.message);
});
```

I have also separated out the AJAX request and set the variable I want to send as a push in $_seesion, checked if the variable has changed in a wile loop and send a notification.

This also doesn't work:

```
function send_notice()
{
  $data = array(
    'title' =>  $_SESSION['obj'],
    'message' => $_SESSION['stat']
  );
  $json = json_encode($data);

  echo "event: pushNotification\n";
  echo "data: $json\n\n";
}

while ($_SESSION['obj'] != 0){
  send_notice();
  $_SESSION['obj'] == 0;
  $_SESSION['stat'] == 0;
}
```

Comment: you cannot import the php file into client js code.

Comment: could you suggest a simple method by which I can receive a post in PHP and push data I get from this post to the client client ?

Comment: The code you have mentioned above is what contains the `push-notifications.php`?

Comment: why are you sending `header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');` instead of `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: Anything output during the processing of an AJAX request becomes part of the AJAX response. Your server needs to send the notification independently of the AJAX. You will need to store the data from the AJAX and have a (looping) process running on the server that detects that newly stored data then sends the data as a server-sent event. i.e. the ajax handler and the code that sends the notifications must be separate processes - i.e. the php that is the event source should be a separate script to the Ajax handler.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Comment: So in your case the notification process is push-notifications.php. You need a separate ajax_listener.php to handle the incoming AJAX requests.

Comment: The `EventSource` connection is made using GET but your Ajax is using POST. Two completely separate http requests. If you make the ajax request first and use the response  as part of the EventSource connection url you could pass the parameters that way

Comment: if i make the Content-Type: application/json fire fox says it isn't able to connect the file, it only is able to connect to the file if the header is text/event-stream. @AlexG

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thakn you sir for you answer, but how to do this? could you show me a small example?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit yes it is sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example that sends an AJAX request to the server and then uses the response data when constructing and initialising the EventSource connection.

```
<?php
    /*******************************************/
    /* Process EventSource connection requests */
    /*******************************************/
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset( 
        $_GET['event'],
        $_GET['object'],
        $_GET['status'] 
    ) && $_GET['event']=='initialise' ){
        
        ob_clean();
        
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        
        function sse( $evtname='iss', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }
        
        $evt='pushNotification';
        $sleep=5;
        
        while( true ){
            // do things... query db? use original data from ajax?
            $payload=array_merge( $_GET, array(
                'time'  =>  time(),
                'rand'  =>  mt_rand(0,9999)
            ));
            
            // send the data back to EventSource client
            call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );
            
            // Send output
            if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @flush();
            
            // wait for defined period before repeating infinite loop
            sleep( $sleep );
        }
        exit();
    }//end of SSE / GET




    /*********************************/
    /* Process the POST AJAX request */
    /*********************************/
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset(
        $_POST['object'],
        $_POST['status']
    )) {
        $thi = $_POST['object'];
        $act = $_POST['status'];
        $update = true;
        /************************************************
            It is unknown what this POST processing does 
            in the real code so here it simply sends 
            back some JSON data.
        */
        $payload=array_merge(
            $_POST,
            array(
                'date'  =>  date( DATE_ATOM ),
                'ip'    =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            )
        );
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $payload ) );
    }// End of POST code
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX & SSE: POST data to server, use response to build SSE connection.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>AJAX & SSE: POST data to server, use response to build SSE connection.</h1>
        <form method='post'>
            <label>Object:<input type='text' name='object' value='Donald Trumps Hairpiece' /></label>
            <label>Status:<input type='text' name='status' value='comical' /></label>
            <input type='button' name='init' value='Initialise AJAX request & trigger SSE connection' />
            <input type='button' name='quit' value='Quit' />
        </form>
        <output></output>
        <script>
            // global variable to refer to the eventsource connection
            let evtsource;
            
            // utility to construct the url with querystring
            const buildurl=function( endpoint, params ){
                let url=new URL( endpoint );
                    url.search = new URLSearchParams( params ).toString();
                return url;
            };
            
            // do something interesting with the SSE response data... this simply prints to the page
            const ssecallback=function(e){
                if( !e.origin == window.location.origin ) return false;
                let json=JSON.parse( e.data );
                let output=document.querySelector('output');
                let div=document.createElement('div');
                    div.textContent=Object.keys( json ).map(k=>[k,json[k]].join('=')).join(', ');
                output.appendChild( div );
            };
            
            // The AJAX response can now be used to create SSE connection url.
            const ajaxcallback=( json )=>{
                let url=buildurl( location.href, json );
                console.log( 'Connect SSE: %c%s', 'color:red', url );
                
                evtsource = new EventSource( url, { withCredentials:false } );
                evtsource.addEventListener( 'pushNotification', ssecallback );              
            };
            
            
            // click the button to send the AJAX request. The ajax callback then launches the SSE/EventSource
            document.querySelector('[type="button"][name="init"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                /* Kill any existing EventSource prior to making fresh AJAX request */
                if( typeof evtsource == 'object' && evtsource instanceof EventSource ){
                    evtsource.close();
                    evtsource=null;
                }
                
                // build the AJAX payload prior to sending request.
                let fd=new FormData( e.target.closest('form') );
                    fd.set('event','initialise');
                    
                // make the ajax request
                fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd })
                    .then( r=>r.json() )
                    .then( ajaxcallback )
                    .catch( alert )
            });
            
            document.querySelector('[type="button"][name="quit"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                if( typeof evtsource == 'object' && evtsource instanceof EventSource ){
                    evtsource.close();
                    evtsource=null;
                    document.querySelector('output').innerHTML='Goodbye';
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time to do this ! you rally made my day !